# Can we use conditionals based on lookbehinds?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a regular expression, with a similar task to this one. This one wants to find prices ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hnRsA2/3)), where a dollar sign must precede or follow a number, but never both.

```
  \b       # "word" boundary
  (?<=\$)  # Assert that current position is preceded by $
  \d+\b    # digits, boundary
  (?!\$)   # Assert that current position is not followed by $
|          # alternation
  \b       # boundary
  (?<!\$)  # Assert that current position not preceded by $
  \d+\b    # digits, boundary
  (?=\$)   # Assert that current position is followed by $
```

Is there a way in PCRE to use a condition to do similar with conditionals. ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJrvdc/1))

```
(                 # capture 1, because we can't quantify lookarounds
  (?<=\$)         # Asserts that $ precedes current position
)?                # close capture 1, make it "optional" (0 or 1 times)

\b                # boundary
\d+               # digits
\b                # boundary
(?(1)             # conditional that capture #1 was a success
  (?!\$)          # if successful, assert that it is not followed by a #
|
  (?=\$)          # unsuccessful, assert that this position is followed by a $
)
```

> **Note:** The word boundaries are important, so that both capture the whole number, otherwise the regex will step backward one step, clipping a digit off a multi-digit number.
>
> Both expressions above match $15, and 16$, but not $17$, as they should. Without the boundaries, they'd match $15, 16, and $1 of $17$.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJrvdc/2)). The solution to the problem is 99 steps, which is an unnecessary sacrifice in this simple example. There are situations where the sacrifice, if any, are more than prudent.

This ended up being very simple. Make capture group 1 *possessive*. This means that whatever it captures, it won't surrender if the regex tries to backtrack. Here that means that once it decides that the number should be preceded by `$`, it later won't let the regex backtrack if the number is also followed by a `$`. It will give up and move on, finding the next boundary followed by digits and looking at its surroundings.

```
(                 # capture 1, because we can't quantify lookarounds
  (?<=\$)         # Asserts that $ precedes current position
)?+               # close capture 1, make it "optional" (0 or 1 times)
                  # the possessive quantifier is the only change to the regex
                    # + is only 'possessive' when it's the second character of a quantifier

\b                # boundary
\d+               # digits
\b                # boundary
(?(1)             # conditional that capture #1 was a success
  (?!\$)          # if successful, assert that it is not followed by a #
|
  (?=\$)          # unsuccessful, assert that this position is followed by a $
)
```

Comment: I see it takes 99 steps to accomplish the task on the input string and not 66.

Comment: @revo Good catch. My initial test didn’t have the fourth plain line, or the fifth accidental blank line. Oops.

Comment: Why do you need lookbehinds and conditional constructs? There would be more optimized ways to do this.